# Sort hash ascending by value using sortBy in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, hash, underscore.js

I used [sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) function in underscore.js library.

I have hash, and I tried to sort it by value as the following:

```
var obj = {x: 2, y: 6, z: 1, q: 4};
_.sortBy(obj)
```

But the output is as the following:

```
[1, 2, 4, 6]
```

But I need to sort it, and return keys with value as the following:

```
{z: 1, x: 2, q: 4, y: 6}
```

How can I return sorted hash using `sortBy` ?

I noticed that `sortBy` function return list, so is there another good solution to sort hash or I need to implement function return sorted hash ?

Comment: In js, the order of object properties is by definition undefined. You can not do what you want without an array or any other extra *container* to hold the correct order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Related to @Ragnar answer. I got solution to solve the question. And return sorted hash.

**Ascending Order**

```
function getSortedHash(inputHash){
  var resultHash = {};

  var keys = Object.keys(inputHash);
  keys.sort(function(a, b) {
    return inputHash[a] - inputHash[b]
  }).forEach(function(k) {
    resultHash[k] = inputHash[k];
  });
  return resultHash;
}
```

**Descending Order**

```
function getSortedHash(inputHash){
  var resultHash = {};

  var keys = Object.keys(inputHash);
  keys.sort(function(a, b) {
    return inputHash[a] - inputHash[b]
  }).reverse().forEach(function(k) {
    resultHash[k] = inputHash[k];
  });
  return resultHash;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There's no such thing as a sorted hash (object) in JavaScript. What you can do is put the keys in an array, iterate that and use the keys to access the object properties.

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.sort(function(a, b) {
    return obj[a] - obj[b]
});

keys.forEach(function(k) {
   console.log(obj[k]);
});
```

Comment: if the values are not integers, consider this sort function: `keys.sort(function byVal(a,b){
  if (obj[a] < obj[b])
    return -1;
  if ( obj[a] > obj[b])
    return 1;
  return 0;
})`

Answer (score 3):

In addition, if you want to return the array in descending order, you can use `reverse()` function:

```
var obj = {x: 2, y: 6, z: 1, q: 4};

var keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.sort(function(a, b) {
    return obj[a] - obj[b]
}).reverse().forEach(function(k) {
   console.log(obj[k]);
});
```

or just like this (thanks to @muistooshort):

```
var obj = {x: 2, y: 6, z: 1, q: 4};

var keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.sort(function(a, b) {
    return obj[b] - obj[a]   //inverted comparison
}).forEach(function(k) {
   console.log(obj[k]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ragnar. You answered before I edited the question. I want to return ascending order But I typed it wrongly :(

Answer (score 1):

More concise form with `reduce`:

```
// asceding order
const sortHash = (hash) => {
  return Object.keys(hash)
    .sort()
    .reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: hash[key] }), {});
};
```

```
// desceding order
const sortHash = (hash) => {
  return Object.keys(hash)
    .sort()
    .reverse()
    .reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: hash[key] }), {});
};
```